# Empty string vs null string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have read on some links that it's good practice to return an **empty** string than **null** because it removes the possibility of `NullPointerException`.

But, if we think from memory perspective, i think empty string does take some heap space as after all it's an object, though empty. So, considering this isn't better to return **null** than **empty** string? And will the same hold true for collection, say `ArrayList`?

Comment: The answer is **depends**.

Comment: An empty `String` object is basically a `char[0]` and an `int`. If you think that's a lot of heap space, well...ok. I've never seen anyone do that though.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ May be that Depends but I am biased with `null`. :)

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder Yes. empty strings causes pain sometimes :P.

Comment: `return "";` in multiple locations DOES NOT waste your heap memory!

In Java, String is **immutable**, which gives Java compiler plenty room to optimise.

The Strings created by string literal (like `"xyz"`, not `new String("...")`) are optimised in String literal pool, there will be no duplicated strings in String literal pool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `null` religious wars, I myself don't think of `null` as bad practice compared to alternatives, but some do. I would certainly think first about what design and API makes sense, before worrying about the performance.

That said I do not think memory is an issue. `""` will be `intern`ed and only one instance of `""` that you return from methods with `return ""` will exist on the heap.

I don't believe it's even infinitesimally faster to return a non-`null` reference either.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you want to return `null`, sometimes you don't. It really **depends** on your logic.

For example, think about a situation where an empty String represents a legal return value. In this case, if you encounter a logical error during the construction of some object, you don't want to return an *empty* String since it's a *legal* return value in your case, so you might want to return `null` to indicate that there's some kind of error.

For example, consider that you got this array: `["Dog1", "Dog2", "Cat", " ", ""]` and you want to write a method that searches for a String in the array:

```
private String getDog(String dog) {
   for(String str : animals) {
      if(str.equals(dog)) {
         return dog;
      }
   }
   return null;
   //If you return an empty String instead
   //it's already a valid member in that array...
   //it won't be an indication that the String doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say returning **null** is always evil, but I personally tend to avoid it.

We usually use **Optional** if available. (either from [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html), [Java 8](http://java.dzone.com/articles/optional-java-8-cheat-sheet), or [Scala](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_options.htm)).

So in your case you would either return `Optional<String>` with some value contained, or returning `Optional.absent()`